# Force non-www/http to www/https only for some specific pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I was wondering is it's possible to force some specific pages from non-www/http to www/https and keep some other ones with non-www/http.

#### Example

From non-www/http to www/https:

http://example.com to https://www.example.com

but these ones will remain non-www and http:

http://example.com/folder1/*

http://example.com/folder2/*

I have tried to add in the htaccess file this rule condition:

```
RewriteEngine On     

# Enable HTTPS and WWW for homepage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/ [R=301,L]

# Disable HTTPS and WWW for all pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Then it should force to https and www just the homepage and leave the other pages like **/folder1/** and **/folder2/** to htpp non-www.

But it seems not working well

Comment: And what does "But it seems not working well" actually mean? Does it work but not as expected? Does it work sometimes? Does something work, other things not, which? Do you get any entries in your error log file? Does the universe implode?

Comment: The second part will never work. It tries to redirect from https protocol to http protocol. None of todays browsers will follow such a redirection for very good reasons. They will all show an error or a warning and prompt the user what to do. There simply is no way around that. Again: for very good reasons...

Comment: Actually this whole question sounds a bit like a "xy problem". So that you did not tell us your actual issue, but ask how you could implement some idea you had which you think could solve your actual issue. I suggest you present your _actual_ issue instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try these :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^folder1.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^folder2.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^folder1.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^folder2.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^folder1.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteCond    %{HTTPS} off       ## http requests only
RewriteRule    ^folder1/  - [L]   ## stop for folder1/ 
RewriteRule    ^folder2/  - [L]   ## stop for folder2/
                                  ## then redirect all other requests:
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$     https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Similarly, you can you regex your skips:

```
RewriteRule    ^folder(\d+)/  - [L]   ## stop redirection for any folder[number]/
```

Or make this a negative `RewriteCond` keeping a single `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteCond    %{HTTPS} off                        ## http requests only
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/folder(\d+)/    ## skip any folder[number]/
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$     https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Etc... Full docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html